# When is "do-almost-nothing" a good idea in CHOMP?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

*Now asked [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454124/is-do-almost-nothing-ever-winning-on-large-chomp-boards):*

The proof by strategy-stealing that [CHOMP](https://wiki.math.wisc.edu/images/Chomp_Sol.pdf) on a rectangular board is a first-player win involves player 1 taking the top-right square on their first move. Of course given the proof-by-contradiction nature of the argument, this does *not* mean that the top-right square is in general a good opening move, and there are plenty of rectangular boards on which it is in fact a losing move for the first player.

*Note: different versions of CHOMP place the "poison square" at different locations. For simplicity, I'm sticking with the convention from the above-linked notes.*

I'd like to know how often it is in fact a good move. (Note: by a strategy stealing argument, if it's winning in a given board it is in fact the only winning move in that board. I missed this at first.)

There are a couple ways to phrase this problem:

> **Question 1**: For fixed $n$, let $c_n$ be the upper asymptotic density of the set of $m$ such that moving in the top-right square is the winning move for the first player on the $m$-by-$n$ board. What is $c_3$?

(It's easy to see that $c_1=0$ and $c_2=1$, so this is the first interesting case. Of course the higher $c_i$s are also interesting, but I worry that they are intractable.)

> **Question 2**: Is it the case that, for every $k$, there are $m,n>k$ such that the top-right square is the winning move for the first player in the $m$-by-$n$ board? (Is this even true for $k=2$?)

Comment: Except for $1\times 2, 2 \times 1,$ and $2\times 2$ rectangles, I find it doubtful that taking the upper right square only is ever a winning opening move.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It's always winning in $2\times n$ I think.

Comment: Huh. So it is. Having looked at the $2\times 2$ case, I feel foolish for overlooking this extension of the same strategy.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Check out the MO version (now linked) - it turns out $6\times 11$, $6\times 15$, and $6\times 27$ all make almost-passing a good idea!

Comment: The recurrence [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/games/chomp.html) makes it easy to answer the question computationally for a $3 \times n$ board: in the notation used there, we want to know the $n$ for which $f(n,n-1) = n$. I am lazy and don't want to write efficient code, so I have only checked that for $n$ up to $1000$, the only case where doing almost nothing is a good idea on a $3\times n$ board is when $n=2$.

Comment: More along these lines: let $(p,q,r)$ with $p\ge q \ge r$ represent a 3-row CHOMP board with $p$ squares in the bottom row, $q$ squares in the middle row, and $r$ squares in the top row. For all $q,r$ there is a unique $p=f(q,r)$ such that $(p,q,r)$ is a P-position; that's the $f$ in the previous comment. Experimentally, it seems like $f(n,n-1)$ stays within a constant of $(1+\frac{\sqrt2}{2})n$ as $n\to\infty$, which would imply $c_3=0$, but that would be hard to show.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry to spam here, but you have a bounty on my question about relations that ensure continuity due to expire in 3 days (which I'm grateful for btw). There's an answer there, but I'm busy preparing a submission and won't be able to chrck, much less accept, it this week. Can you take a look and see if the bounty should be awarded?

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer too big for a comment:

For a $3×n$ board, the "do almost nothing" move is never the right move.  Using the recurrence from [this page](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/games/chomp.html):

> Let f(q,r) be the unique p such that (p,q,r) is a P-position. (Here (p,q,r) stands for (p,min(p,q),min(p,q,r)).) There is a simple recurrence for f(q,r):
>
> If r > q, then f(q,r) = f(q,q). (That is, f is constant on verticals above the diagonal.) Otherwise, if f(q-1,r) < q, then f(q,r) = f(q-1,r). (That is, if f(q,r) = q then f remains constant on the rest of this row.) If neither case occurs, then f(q,r) is the smallest positive integer not among f(a,r) for a < q or among f(q,b) for b < r.

The author of that page draws a table:

```
24|                                                                       42
23|                                                                    40 41
22|                                                                 39 38 40
21|                                                              37 38 36 39
20|                                                           35 36 37 33 38
19|                                                        34 33 35 36 31 37
18|                                                     32 33 31 29 35 34 36
17|                                                  30 31 29 32 33 34 26 35
16|                                               28 29 26 31 30 32 33 23 23
15|                                            27 26 28 29 30 23 31 22 22 22
14|                                         25 26 23 27 28 22 29 30 31 32 33
13|                                      24 23 22 25 26 27 19 19 19 19 19 19
12|                                   21 23 22 24 19 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17
11|                                20 19 22 17 23 24 25 21 26 27 28 29 30 31
10|                             18 19 20 21 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14
 9|                          16 17 14 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 8|                       15 14 16 17 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
 7|                    13 14 12 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 6|                 11 12 13  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
 5|              10  9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 4|            8  9 10  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
 3|         6  7  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
 2|      4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 1|   3  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 0|1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
q: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

He then notes that elements on the diagonal are always the largest in their column:

> The column (q,*) contains q+1 different numbers f(q,r), all of them positive integers, so f(q,r) > q. It follows that f(q,r) is the smallest element that does not occur earlier in the same row or column. Since the numbers f(q,s) are not at the (q,r) position, it follows that they all occur earlier in row (*,r), but not at (t,r) with t <= r since above the diagonal verticals are constant. So, they all occur at (t,r) with r+1 <= t <= q-1. But there are more numbers s than positions t, contradiction.

This is easily extended to show that $f(q,q-1)$ is at most *third* greatest.  But there are $q-2$ numbers below $f(q,q-1)$ - and neither $1$ nor $3$ are in the column, so $f(q,q-1)$ is at least $q+1$.

### Finite for any $m>2$ on boards $m×n$

A similar table can be created for any $m$ - just much more complicated because it would have more dimensions. And the same argument would apply to the diagonal of the table - $f(k,k,k)$ would be the greatest value in its column, and so on. $f(k,k,k-1)$ would be at least the *fifth* greatest, and so on.

Thus, for every $m>2$ there exists an $N$ such that "do almost nothing" is a losing move on all boards $m×n$, where $n>N$.

Given that $N$ increases with $m$, I think it's safe to say that there are no solutions for $m=4,5$ (I have with computer search checked boards up to $6×65$).